# Different content in Watch app and iOS App in CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, ios-app-group, watchos-3

I have an iOS app target and an watchOS target in my project. Furthermore I have a framework for the iOS app where my CoreData model and some classes are located in. In another framework for the watchOS app I have the same classes. 
Now I want to access the same data in my iOS app and my watchOS app. I already have an app group where the CoreData is normally saved in.
But when I open the app on the watch there is an empty store with no data and on the phone there is the normal store. 
What mistake did I do? Do you have any tips for me?

I am using this code to create the persistent store:

```
    var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)

    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let url = fileManager.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "MYGROUP")?.appendingPathComponent("XXX.sqlite")

    var error: NSError? = nil
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."

    var options = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:true, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true]

    do {
        try coordinator!.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: url, options: options)
```

Thanks

Comment: Show the code how you setup persistantStoreCoordinator.

Comment: I added it to my original question

Comment: Looks good to me. Did you log the directory and compare in-between app and watch?